# Infinispan 8.0.1 crashing when I remove a member from the cluster

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, infinispan, jgroups, infinispan-8

I am using play framework version 2.3.8 and the plugin(https://github.com/n4cer/playInfinispanCachePlugin) to integrate infinispan(version 8.0.1 with jgroups) in my app for distribution cache. Configuration for the infinispan can be found in the plugin project and I am using S3_PING protocol.

This setup working well until I remove a member from the cluster. When I remove a member from the cluster, other active members in the cluster slowly going down and throwing errors, finally my application is not responding. This issue get resolved when I restart all the members. How to make it work when I remove a member from the cluster?

I see this exception

```
org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
        at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:172) ~[org.infinispan.infinispan-commons-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:869) ~[org.infinispan.infinispan-core-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeStartMethods(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:638) ~[org.infinispan.infinispan-core-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:627) ~[org.infinispan.infinispan-core-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:530) ~[org.infinispan.infinispan-core-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache ___defaultcache on ri-stress-ui1-new-52199
        at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete(StateTransferManagerImpl.java:225) ~[org.infinispan.infinispan-core-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen, but you are using a really old version of Infinispan.
You should really upgrade to a current version of Infinispan such as 10.1.8.Final.
Can you also include logs to help us understand and debug your issue ?

Comment: I am getting these two errors. "org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000299: Unable to acquire lock after 10 seconds for key" and "o.i.i.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleAll - ISPN000136: Execution error
org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception"